# Passing each value in a field(column) , of a csv file as a parameter to awk. unix

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, git-bash

I have written a script that will check the contents of `$path` and print the `i+1` value in the file mentioned in the `$path`.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter number of records"
read num
count=1
while [ $count -le $num ]
do
 echo "Enter path"
 read path
 var2=`echo "${path##*/}"`
 var3=`awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i == "'${var2}'"} print $(i+1)}' ${path} | head -1`
 echo "done,$var3" >> result.csv
 ((count++))
done
```

If the value of `$path` was `/c/training/sample.sh` or `/c/training/textfile`, with the below content

**sample.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#sample.sh 120
<psuedo-code>
```

**textfile.txt**

```
textfile.txt 0
This is random text
```

**result.csv** or how the output csv file should look like

```
done,120
done,0
```

So instead of reading the path each time, how can I read all the paths, if they are stored in a separated csv file.

**Sampleinput.csv**

```
/c/training/sample.sh,User1
/c/training/textfile.txt,USer2
```

How can I implement the `awk` mentioned above so that it will read each value in field 1 of the **Sampleinput.csv** and do the same thing

Comment: Regarding `i=1;I<NF` in your code - `i` is not the same variable as `I`. Also, copy/paste this script and any other shell script you write into http://shellcheck.net til you're more familiar with the fundamentals.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks Ed, I have rectified the mistake

Comment: you still haven't run it through http://shellcheck.net as the [bash tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) instructs you to do before posting a question, though, as it still contains several errors that tool would tell you about.

Answer (score 0):

A much more versatile and usable arrangement is to pass the paths as parameters to the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'FNR == 1 { path=FILENAME; sub(/.*\//, "", path) }
  $0 ~ path && / [0-9]+$/ { print path "," 0+$NF; nextfile }' "$@"
```

The [`nextfile` statement is included in POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588906/is-awks-nextfile-specified-in-posix) but might not be supported if you have a really old Awk or are using a non-POSIX system.

Usage:

```
scriptname /c/training/sample.sh /c/training/textfile >>result.csv
```

Comment: passing the paths as parameters would be useful if the number of inputs is minimal. I just used two files as examples for the question. hence reading from a separate csv file

Comment: You can use `xargs` to pass in an arbitrary number of paths. Having scripts require interactive I/O is extremely clumsy and limits their usability both for calling from other scripts and for users who have a shell with tab completion, history, redirection etc.

Comment: true, but again practically it may not be the best option to type out all the paths. At least in this scenrario

Comment: Huh? You are forced to enter them one by one in the design you proposed. With a script which accepts file name arguments, you can trivially use e.g. wildcards, shell history, and/or a text file to automate that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do (untested) using GNU awk for gensub(), ARGIND, nextfile, and ENDFILE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS= read -p 'Enter number of records: ' -r num

awk -v maxFiles="$num" '
    BEGIN { OFS="," }
    ARGIND == 1 {
        if ( ARGC < maxFiles ) {
            ARGV[ARGC++] = gensub(/,.*/,"",1)
        }
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        fname = gensub(".*/","",1,FILENAME)
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ( gensub(/^#+/,"",1,$i) == fname ) {
                val = $(i+1)
                nextfile
            }
        }
    }
    ENDFILE {
        if ( ARGIND > 1 ) {
            print "done", val
        }
        val = 0
    }
' Sampleinput.csv > result.csv
```

Comment: I do not have much knowledge using gensub, ARGIND. But let me go through them to understand this solution